# Guava RateLimiter in JAVA

Tags: java, guava, rate

I want to send a request to an external API with a 5/second rate like this:

```
//limit sending rate to 5 per second
      RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(5);
```

Then I pass this rateLimiter to the method (which is called through a for):

```
for(...){
    broadcastToken = sendTemplateService.sendBroadcastPetition(broadcastInput, rateLimiter);
}
```

Inside this method I do a lot of stuff:

```
public BroadcastToken sendBroadcastPetition(BroadcastInput broadcastInput, RateLimiter rateLimiter) {
//do a lot of stuff
rateLimiter.acquire();
restTemplate.exchange(broadcastUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
}
```

Is my aproach correct? I dont want the whole method to do 5 per second, what i want is the call to the API to be 5 per second max.

this  RateLimiter.create(5) will only affect the next line?

Answer (score 2):

The thing that's been rate-limited is the acquisition of permits from the `RateLimiter` object. You've created a `RateLimiter` that will grant at most 5 permits per second. So, **assuming you have only one `RateLimiter`**, you'll only be able to do `rateLimiter.acquire()` 5 times per second and therefore you'll only run the next line that calls `restTemplate.exchange` 5 times per second too.

Passing the `RateLimiter` into the function uses it seems a little strange, though. What class has the responsibility for ensuring that `restTemplate.exchange` is only called 5 times per second? If it is the class of `sendBroadcastPetition` (whatever it is), then that class should create the `RateLimiter` (or accept one as a constructor argument) and always use that one. The way it is now, the caller of `sendBroadcastPetition` can defeat the rate limit by passing in a different `RateLimiter` every time. If it's the caller that is responsible for enforcing the rate limit, then maybe call `acquire` before calling `sendBroadcastPetition` and don't pass the `RateLimiter` in.

Comment: but if I put "RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(5)" inside "sendBroadcastPetition" wouldn't it restart every time it is called by the outside for?

Comment: Yes. You want to create it in the constructor of whatever class contains `sendBroadcastPetition`. Is `sendBroadcastPetition` a static method?

Comment: it is a public class with a @Service tag in spring. Question: What you mean by: " the caller of sendBroadcastPetition can defeat the rate limit" is that if I call this method through another class with another RateLimiter. But in this only scenario it wouldn't defeated it, right?